# CSS: set style only for li that have inside an ul

Tags: css, html-lists

I have an unordered list (ul) with some list items (li). One of this have another unordered list inside (ul). Now, I want to se to all these li the same stylesheet, except for the li that have another unordered list inside.

```
<ul>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>Another Element</li>
    <li>Special Element
        <ul>
            <li>Child</li>
            <li>Child</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can I set CSS without set a specific class for the special li?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current CSS specs, this is not possible. There is no selector for "an element that contains some specific content". It may be possible in CSS4, but as of now, you will have to take special measures to single out the "special" li.

```
<ul>
    <li>Element</li>
    <li>Another Element</li>
    <li class="specialelement">Special Element
        <ul>
            <li>Child</li>
            <li>Child</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and give class `.specialelement` a style of its own.

Comment: I've supposed this was the only solution for my problem, for now, I mean. CSS rules will be more smart as now! wonderful. Thanks to all of you for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

`ul ul li { your-rules: here; }`

I recommend giving this a read, it will help you understand the cascade and specificity: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/inheritancecascade

-- edit --

Sorry, just realised you want to style the `li`, not the `ul li` inside.

`li:nth-child(3) { your-rules: here; }`

NOTE: this will affect your inner `li`s as well if there are three or more.

Read http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/ to understand the rule I've suggested you use.

Comment: I think you read the question wrong, he want only the li-items that does not contain another unordered list to be selected. This will only selected the li items in the second unordered list.

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
ul li > li {
   some style
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this? It doesn't work, because it assumes an `li` as a direct child of an `li`, which is impossible (the `ul` is in between). But even if it would work, it still wouldn't be the answer to the question. Read the question again.